# Jade Include not working (on Extended template)

Tags: node.js, templates, pug

Simple question:
I'm starting a new small project where I have 1 jade file for variables,1 jade file for layout,1 jade file for mixins and finally 1 file for a template.

When I try to use imported **variables from the external file, they aren't being loaded** into the template, whereas the mixins do.

When page1.jade is processed, mixins are imported correctly, layout is extended correctly, but variable from styles.jade is not imported (or that is what is seems) as the mixins is unable to reach the variable *styleCenterMain* to be assigned to the style attribute).

**page1.jade:**

```
include mixins.jade
include styles.jade
extends layout.jade

block append wholeContent   

block append wholeContent
    div.test1 Hi world

block append wholeContent
    div.test2 Hi Again

block append wholeContent   
    +moduleMain()
        p Some content to pass to mixin
```

**mixins.jade:** (Here is where a get the Error.)

```
mixin moduleMain()
  table(style=styleCenterMain width="100%" height="100%")
```

**style.jade.**

```
- styleCenterMain ="margin-left: 0; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0; vertical-align: top;"
```

**layout.jade (xml file):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
doctype html

    head        

    body
        <!-- main content -->   

        div(style="background-color:#f2f4f5; margin:0 auto;")
            block wholeContent
```

Can anyone give a hint of why style.jade is not imported or why its variable are not accessed by the mixin?

Thanks a lot beforehand

Answer (score 1):

First of all you included **styles** and named *style* I would check on that.

Mixins are a good way for you to pass a variable to the included script but they have to receive it, they have their own scope!

If you fix the import name and do this it should solve it:

**mixins.jade**

```
mixin moduleMain(desiredStyle)
  table(style=desiredStyle width="100%" height="100%")
```

**page1.jade**

```
....
block append wholeContent   
+moduleMain(styleCenterMain)
    p Some content to pass to mixin
```

Comment: Hi FabioCosta (the wrong name was a typing mistake, sorry about that :) About variables, I used an import as i'll have plenty of them and it would be annoying to pass them all one by one to the mixin. As for the scope, that's what I thought, but I'm reading a Jade book where it says (or at least I understood) that there's no such scope in Jade files, like all declared variables are kind of "global"...

Comment: You could use an object if the vars will be plenty, about the scoped if i am not mistaken every jade file regardless of includes will be treated as one single file, so yes all the vars will be global but i think mixins will only access their own vars. You could use a block on the mixin if there is a lot of code that you want to reuse